# Javascript sub function error

Tags: javascript

```
function Person() {
}
Function.prototype.subfuncname = function(name) {
  var old = this[name];
  this[name] = function() {
    console.log('testing');
  }
}   
Person.subfuncname("test");
var pe = new Person();

pe.test('test');
```

expect get 'testing' but get an error (pe.test is not a function)

Please help

Comment: Please can you include your definition of 'Person'?

Comment: Thanks for reply, i have added the code

Comment: Where does test is defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just correcting your code.

Instead of

```
this[name]=function(){
   console.log('testing');
}
```

make it

```
this.prototype[name]=function(){
   console.log('testing');
}
```

That'll do the trick.

```js
function Person(){
    
}
    
Function.prototype.subfuncname=function(name){
    
  this.prototype[name]=function(){
       alert('It works!');
     }
  }   
    
Person.subfuncname("test");
var pe=new Person();
    
pe.test('test');
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `subfuncname` function `Person` object's prototype. Also `subfuncname` must be called on the instance.

```
function Person() {}
Person.prototype.subfuncname = function(name) {
  var old = this[name];
  this[name] = function() {
    console.log('testing');
  };
};
var pe = new Person();
pe.subfuncname("test");
pe.test('test');
```

Answer (score 0):

The only code you need to get the intended result is:

```js
   function Person() {
     this.test = function(string) {
       console.log(string);
     }
   }
   var pe = new Person();
   pe.test('testing');
```

If you want the function on the prototype of the Person object you can also do this:

```js
function Person() {

}

Person.prototype.test = function(string) {
  console.log('testing');
}

var pe = new Person();
pe.test('test');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function Person(){

}

Person.prototype.subfuncname = function (txt) {
   console.log(txt);
    alert(txt);
};

var pe=new Person();
pe.subfuncname("Jason");
```

[Test case](https://jsfiddle.net/q5hyavjd/1/)